# Pandas String that Begins with Quotes Issue

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a pandas df where one column contains the positions of hockey players. The column looks like this:

```
Pos
"D"
"D"
"D"
"D"
"D"
"D"
"D"
"D"
"L"
"L","R"
"L","R"
"L","R"
"L","R"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L"
"L","C"
```

I'd like to convert the values in this column to either 'D' or 'F'. The code I have to do this is:

```
    df.loc[df['Pos'] == '''\"D\"''', 'Pos'] = 'D'
    df.loc[df['Pos'] != '''\"D\"''', 'Pos'] = 'F'
```

However, I believe my code is having issues dealing with the beginning double quotes of the string.
I've tried a bunch of different variations to handle the quotes such as ("\"D\"", '''"D"''') but the output is still incorrect. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing simply:

```
df['POS'] = df['POS'].apply(lambda x: 'D' if 'D' in x else 'F')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!